# Convert a time series from minutes to Day period

Tags: r, time-series

I've got an R time series object that is measured in 1 hour intervals.

```
library(lubridate)
library(timeSeries)

set.seed(100)
c <- Sys.time()
d <- c + hours(1:200)
e <- rnorm(200)
f <- data.frame(d,e)
g <- as.timeSeries(f)
```

I would like to convert this to a daily time, , I am fine with using the average or value of the data column for this conversion.

The outcome would be a time series object with one entry per day whose value is the average of all the hourly values of that particular day.

How can this be done?

Comment: Code posted should be *reproducible*.  Do not use random numbers without settng the seed and include all `library` statements.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, thanks for the heads up.  That's a great idea, though in this case it doesn't matter at all.

Comment: And the `hours` and `as.timeSeries` functions come from which packages?

Comment: @eipi10 hours comes from lubridate and as.timeSeries comes from the timeSeries package

Comment: @chollida Please edit your OP to include all the information to make it reproducible.

Comment: "I would like to convert this to a daily time"... what do You exactly mean? What output are You expecting?

Answer (score 0):

First, take advantage of `lubridate` package to calculate date:

```
library(lubridate) 
f$date <- floor_date(ymd_hms(f$d), "day")
```

Then, calculate average for given day with

```
library(dplyr)
dplyr::group_by(f, date) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(avg = mean(e))
```

And use this for time series.

Comment: These are my two cents. Specify library of 'as.timeSeries' function to get more insight.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I don't believe that answer's my question.  That just just converts a date to a different format, my timeseries would still have multiple entries for  a particular day:)

Comment: Edited after I hopefully understood what are You after.